# Extra namespace adding in IE while appending xml to div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

```
var svgElem = data.childNodes[0];//gets svg element

var insertSvgTag =      
  "<g transform="scale(0.34) translate(75,60)">" + svgElem.outerHTML + '</g>';

 var wrapper = document.createElement('div');
 wrapper.innerHTML = insertSvgTag;
```

At the end I have to append wrapper as child of another object.

w  hen I see the innerHTML I get extra namespace

```
 **xmlns:NS1=\"\"  NS1:xmlns:xml=\"http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace\"**
```

I tried another approach:

```
var wrapper = document.**createElementNS**('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'g');

wrapper.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/', 'xmlns', 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg');

wrapper.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/', 'xmlns:xlink', 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink');
```

this gets rid of extra namespace but when I try adding it to another svg object i get the same extra namespace this time while adding child to parent.

This is causing my svg to fail opening.

I googled a lot. followed post: [Internet Explorer XML/SVG Custom Namespacing - Extra/Wrong Namespaces Generated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21539423/internet-explorer-xml-svg-custom-namespacing-extra-wrong-namespaces-generated),
I tried: new DOMParser().parseFromString(content, 'text/xml')
Its not working for me. I think i am doing something wrong. Can any point out whats going wrong?

@dmccabe
@Thomas W

Comment: SVG group elements have to be inside an `<svg>` element.  You can't insert them directly in a `<div>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok. Came up with this solution:

```
            var insertSvgTag =
            '<g transform="scale(0.34) translate(75,60)">' + svgElem.outerHTML + '</g>';

            var wrapper = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'g');
            wrapper.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/', 'xmlns', 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg');
            wrapper.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/', 'xmlns:xlink', 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink');
            wrapper.setAttribute("transform", "scale(0.34) translate(75,60)");

            var xmlString = insertSvgTag        
            , parser = new DOMParser()
            , doc = parser.parseFromString(xmlString, "image/svg+xml");
            doc.firstChild.firstChild.removeAttribute("requiredFeatures");                  
            doc.firstChild.firstChild.removeAttribute("requiredExtensions");
            doc.firstChild.firstChild.removeAttribute("systemLanguage");
            wrapper.appendChild(doc.firstChild.firstChild);
```

as pointed out in comment by paul i cannot add html element to svg element and vice versa. if you do then I was getting following added:

```
 xmlns:NS1=\"\"  NS1:xmlns:xml=\"http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace\"
```

parser.parseFromString is required to convert string to svg dom structure. After all this the svg **still wasn't showing up**. when I **removed following three attributes** from the svg element svg displayed correctly!!:
requiredFeatures,requiredExtensions and systemLanguage //remove these attributes.